# Lets Encrypt Auto Renew Quiet Mode Error

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I have installed let's encrypt with Nginx configuration with DNS validation mode, As instructed on the documentation to auto-renew, I added the below entry:

```
15 3 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew --quiet
```

However, this didn't work, so I run it in the command line to see what happened. I get the error below, I do understand that port 80/443 is in use by Nginx and I have to stop it when I renew it manually, I wonder how do I set it up in AUTO RENEW mode, i.e add stop Nginx before this cronjob and restart after it? But it's a bit too dangerous to do this on a cronjob as if the Nginx fails it creates a lot of downtimes.

```
[centos]# /usr/bin/certbot renew --quiet
Attempting to renew cert (example.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf produced an 
unexpected error: 
Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.. Skipping.

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run certbot with the [`--nginx`](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#nginx) or [`--webroot`](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot) parameter, as documented, to have it use your running nginx instead of starting it's open webserver.

```
certbot renew --quiet --nginx
```

or

```
certbot renew --quiet --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/html
```

Don't forget to also use the `--deploy-hook` parameter to reload your nginx after a successful renewal.

Note: you must install the nginx plugin if you haven't already installed it, with below command.

```
yum install python-certbot-nginx
```

Comment: i still get a error "produced an unexpected error: The requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed. Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:"

Comment: Then install the plugin?

Comment: iirc you don't even need it for the webroot parameter. The nginx plugin will configure the nginx configuration automatically.

Comment: @user1179459 Make sure you take *off* the `--nginx` when adding the `--webroot` parameter.